# Return values from left join only if it exists, otherwise from the main table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Owners]
(
    [OwnerId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AccessToken] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [TokenSecret] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tweets]
(
    [TweetId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    [ReferenceId] [int] NULL,
    [TweetContent] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ReferenceType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AccessToken] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [TokenSecret] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
)
```

I would like to return all fields of `tweets`, and based on if there is an `owners` for the tweet, the `AccessToken/TokenSecret` will come from the `owner` table, if not then it will come from the `tweets` table.

I am having a hard time figuring out the best/efficient way to write this query.

This is what I have so far  (only returns from main table, not owner if there is one)

```
SELECT *  
FROM Tweets t
LEFT JOIN Owners o ON t.ReferenceId = o.OwnerId
WHERE t.ReferenceType = 1
```

I am using SQL Server 2017, in the tweet table, `ReferenceId` is the ownerid correspondence to he `tweets` table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [`coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) would be helpful to select the first non-null value:

```
select coalesce(o.AccessToken, t.AccessToken) as actualAccessToken [...]
```